# Proving a multivariable function is a constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Say we have $f:\Bbb{R^2}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ satisfying the following property:

$f$ is differentiable everywhere and for every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$, $xf_x(x,y)+yf_y(x,y)=0$. I want to prove that $f$ is constant. From a theorem we proved, since $\Bbb{R^2}$ is path-connected, it's enought to prove that the differential is identically $0$.

Since $f$ is differentiable, we get that $xf_x(x,y)+yf_y(x,y)=<\nabla f(x,y),(x,y)>=D_vf(x,y)=0$ - meaning every directional derivative at the point $(x,y)$ in the direction of $(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)$ is $0$, but I can't see how this helps me (if it even has anything to do with the solution). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the directional derivative of function $f$ along the nonzero vector $v$ at certain point is equal to $0$, it means that the function $f$ is constant in that direction. If the function is constant in every arbitrary direction and for any arbitrary point $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then it is constant everywhere.

If $D_v f(x_0)=0$, then $f$ is constant in the direction $v$ which means if you consider the values of $f$ *along the line* in the direction $v$, you find that:

$$ f(x_0+tv) = f(x_0) + t D_vf(x_0) + o(t) = f(x_0) + o(t). $$

(Recall that $o(t)$ is some function of $t$ such that $o(t)/t \to 0$ as $t \to 0$, by well-known asymptotic theory)

Always recall that the directional derivative gives you a real number that measures how much the function increases or decreases if you consider points in the direction given by ${v}$, hence if $\nabla f(x,y) \cdot v= 0$ then the function is neither increasing nor decreasing when you consider points in the direction of ${v}$.

Comment: can you please address me to the proof of the theorem you just stated? Never heard of it. And it's not exactly true that it's constant in every arbitrary direction and for every arbitrary point. It's constant for every arbitrary point in a specific direction.

Comment: It is the same as in the real line.

Answer (score 2):

Take $(a,b)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ and define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&t&\mapsto&(ta,tb).\end{array}$$This function is differentiable, and therefore we have, by the chain rule\begin{align}(f\circ\varphi)'(t)&=D_f(\varphi(t)).D_\varphi(t)\\&=af_x(ta,tb)+bf_y(ta,tb).\end{align}If $t>0$, we have$$(f\circ\varphi)'(t)=\frac1t\bigl(taf_x(ta,tb)+tbf_y(ta,tb)\bigr)=0.$$So $f\circ\varphi$ is constant on $(0,\infty)$. Let $k\in\Bbb R$ be such that $f\circ\varphi=k$. Since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous and therefore we have $k=\lim_{t \to 0^+} f(ta,tb)=f(0,0)$.

If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ we can write it as $(ta,tb)$ for $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$ and $t>0$ and, by what was proved above, $f(x,y)=f(ta,tb)=f(0,0)$.

Comment: Nice method, to use $\varphi$ to parametrize the curve, then use the condition and to get the result! (Only I think there is a typo in the chain rule: not $D_g(t)$ but $D_\varphi(t)$

Comment: @SonGohan I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Jośe Carlos Santos Thank you. If I may ask what gave you the idea to define such function?

Comment: I was looking for a function such that, if I differentiated it, the expression $xf_x+yf_y$ would appear. That would help me to prove that the function was constant. And then I thought about $t\mapsto f(ta,tb)$.